# Extending String prototype. Cannot both specifiy accessors and a value or writable attribute

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, azure-functions, mocha.js

I am creating this custom method inside Object, Array, and String. When I run it on the Azure function app it works, no issue there, but when I start to test it using Mocha/Chai. It gives me below error:

**`TypeError: Invalid property descriptor. Cannot both specify accessors and a value or writable attribute, #<Object>`**

Here is my code,

```
// declare global{
  interface String {
    contains(s: string): boolean;
  }

  interface Object {
    contains(s: string) : boolean;
  }
// }
 
// String
String.prototype.contains = function (s: string) : boolean {
  return String(this).includes(s);
};

// Object
Object.prototype.contains = function (s: string): boolean {
  return Object(this).hasOwnProperty(s);
}

//export {};
```

I import it into my function.
Note: This function works well in live/local on its own.

```
import 'custom/prototype/file';

export const myFunction : Function = (s: string) : Object => {
   const bool : boolean = s.contains('look for this string');
   const obj = { name: "string" };
   const fbool : boolean = obj.contains('name');
   
   return {
     foo: s
     fboo: fbool
   };
}
```

Now in my test.spec.ts file I ran a test using the **myFunction** above.

I do not understand why it's giving me this error when it has no issues running by itself.

```
import { myFunction } from 'index/file';
import 'custom/prototype/file';

describe.skip('test case', () => {
   it('test',() => {
     const object = myFunction('this is a random string');
   });
});
```

Here is the full error log:

```
TypeError: Invalid property descriptor. Cannot both specify accessors and a value or writable attribute, #<Object>
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\test1\test\test azure\utils\defaultContext.ts:2:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Module.m._compile (D:\test1\test\test azure\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (D:\test1\test\test azure\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:442:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\test1\test\test azure\tests\DV_Musculoskeletal.spec.ts:3:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Module.m._compile (D:\test1\test\test azure\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (D:\test1\test\test azure\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:442:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.implementationOfRequireOrImportForUnstableEsm [as requireOrImport] (D:\test1\test\test azure\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:101:12)
    at Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (D:\test1\test\test azure\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:88:34)
    at Mocha.loadFilesAsync (D:\test1\test\test azure\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:467:19)
    at singleRun (D:\test1\test\test azure\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:125:15)
    at exports.runMocha (D:\test1\test\test azure\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:190:10)
    at Object.exports.handler (D:\test1\test\test azure\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:366:11)
    at D:\test1\test\test azure\node_modules\yargs\build\index.cjs:443:71
```

Comment: Just a reminder that modifying prototypes of built-ins is rarely if ever a good idea...

Comment: The stack trace points to the file `\utils\defaultContext.ts` have looked at that yet?